# SSL Socket stuck in CLOSE_WAIT

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, gwt, ssl

I have a standalone application which is listening into the 42555 port.

And the GWT application was deployed into the Tomcat server (Version 6). The GWT application communicate with the Standalone server through the SSL Sockets. For each user session three sockets were established between the applications. When the user logs out we disconnect the connection and close the socket. But when i do the netstat in the Linux machine (both standalone and tomcat) i can able to see the 3 connections (per user basis) hung in CLOSE_WAIT state.

**When user Active. The netstat give the following**

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60143             127.0.0.1:42555             ESTABLISHED 12746/tomcat
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60144             127.0.0.1:42555             ESTABLISHED 12746/tomcat
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60145             127.0.0.1:42555             ESTABLISHED 12746/tomcat
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42555             127.0.0.1:60143             ESTABLISHED 30525/./standalone_server
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42555             127.0.0.1:60144             ESTABLISHED 30525/./standalone_server
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42555             127.0.0.1:60145             ESTABLISHED 30525/./standalone_server
```

**After the user log out and socket disconnect/close. netstat gives**

```
tcp       70      0 127.0.0.1:60143             127.0.0.1:42555             CLOSE_WAIT  12746/tomcat          off (0.00/0/0)
tcp       70      0 127.0.0.1:60145             127.0.0.1:42555             CLOSE_WAIT  12746/tomcat          off (0.00/0/0)
tcp       70      0 127.0.0.1:60144             127.0.0.1:42555             CLOSE_WAIT  12746/tomcat          off (0.00/0/0)
```

When the user clicks logout in the client side, i'm closing the inputStream, outputStream and then socket. In the standalone server side the sockets are kept in a Map (sockets are mapped the session basis) and it's closed after 2 hours (based on last request from the socket).

After seeing all this i'm not able to identify the issue. Based on the netstat it's showing that tomcat application established socket were not closed perfectly. But when i ran the server in the local windows machine with Dev mode (gwt application) the sockets are closing perfectly. This proves that there is no issue with application level. But when i googled for CLOSE_WAIT state it's nothing to make sense on tomcat side also.

Can someone point me where the mistake had happened?

PS : i'm newbie in network and tcp/ssl stack and the netstat of logout taken after 2 hours only.

Comment: I'm not able to completely follow your description but "..in the standalone server side the sockets are kept in a Map..." sounds like you do not close the sockets. This would result in CLOSE_WAIT.

Comment: No. We do close the sockets in the standalone server also. it's not closed immediately but after a couple of hours.